# web3.personal.unlockAccount creates too many nodejs defunct processes

Tags: web3js, nodejs

I am getting a lot of [nodejs] [defunct] process when run this code. Is there a way to check if an account is already unlocked or lock the account to properly close the nodejs process it starts so that there are not too many nodejs defunct processes.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
let txHashArray = [];

try {
    if (web3.isConnected()) {

        const abi = '[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_int","type":"uint16"}],"name":"set","outputs":[{"name":"arrayLength","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"length","outputs":[{"name":"arrayLength","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]';
        const contract = web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(abi));
        const contractAddress = '0x4D0f2e99a871A276da395538C8107275C17bCe12';
        contractInstance = contract.at();

        for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            web3.personal.unlockAccount(web3Config.defaultAccount,
                web3Config.defaultAccountPwd);
            /*

            const txHash = contractInstance.set(i,{from:web3Config.defaultAccount, gas:'9040000', gasPrice:'0'});

            txHashArray.push(txHash);         
            */

            console.log(i)
        }
        /*
        // Write txHash to file to check later
        var txfile = fs.createWriteStream('txfile.csv');
        txfile.on('error', function(err) { /* error handling */ });
        txHashArray.forEach(function(v) { 
            txfile.write(v + '\n'); 
        });
        txfile.end();
        */

    } else {
        console.log('web3 is not connected');
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

Comment: Hi there. Is there any reason for the `unlockAccount` call to be inside the loop?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks i am using parity client.  By default unlocking the account can only sign on transaction https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-personal-module#personal_unlockaccount.  i have not found the setting that will permanently enable unlocking so that i can use the third param to set the unlocking duration.  that is why i need to unlock inside the loop

Comment: Without considering the security implications, you should just be able to pass `0` as the third parameter to unlock indefinitely.